# How do I do NOT in LINQ?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

For a SQL query like this, how do I translate this to linq?

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE NOT (t.col1 = 1 AND t.col2 = 2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var result = from t in table1
             where !(t.col1 == 1 && t.col2 == 2)
             select t;
```

Or, if you want lambda syntax, it would be:

```
var result = table1.Where(t => !(t.col1 == 1 && t.col2 == 2));
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am using the lambda expression syntax

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do this:

```
var result = from t in table1 where t.col1 != 1 && t.col2 != 2 select t;
```

or

```
var result = table1.Where(t => t.col1 != 1 && t.col2 != 2);
```

This isn't much different from the answer above, but I think it's more straight-forward.

Comment: Hi @Don Rolling, good answer in SQL. But take another look, the question was asking for an answer in LINQ